# Load remote markdown file from python

Tags: python, markdown

I need to read an .md file with python and store the content somewhere else.
When I use this code, I get HTML, but I only need the markdown code.

```
doc_url = 'https://gitlab.com/quanzhang/cloud-deploy-component-prod/-/blob/main/README.md'  
with urllib.request.urlopen(doc_url) as url:
  text = url.read()
```

Comment: What if you put `?plain=1` at the end of the URL?

Comment: open raw and download it and save it

Comment: you don' want `blob` in your url, you want `raw`

Comment: Hi @diggusbickus, it works, but when I see the retrieved content it starts with "b" and all new lines are displayed as "\n". Why ?

Comment: you need to decode the result `text = url.read().decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the **raw** file:

```py
import urllib.request

from pathlib import Path

REPO_URL = "https://gitlab.com/quanzhang/cloud-deploy-component-prod"

DOC_URL = f"{REPO_URL}/-/raw/main/README.md"

DOWNLOAD_FOLDER = r"c:\temp"  

with urllib.request.urlopen(DOC_URL) as response:
    with (Path(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER) / Path(DOC_URL).name).open("wb") as file:
        file.write(response.read())
```

Side note: Depending on your needs consider using [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of `urllib`.

Comment: it works perfect! BTW, is there any way to do it on the fly without download it ?

Comment: One more question, how can I do the same but in a private repository? I already have the token, but I don't understand how to create the URL (path to the file). It seems to be different

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a private repository nor an account. If you have a token maybe try to add `?private_token=YOUR_TOKEN` to the URL. However, not sure if that works. You may have to use their API which is documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/).